# How to archive file from folder using ZipFile c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

[image][image]I have to take a file from a folder and make a archive in another folder.
I use this code but get an error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid.
```

I use this code:

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Info = "";
            string startPath = @"D:\dosfiles\SYNOPD\SYNOPD$$.PD\" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + @"\" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + @"\" + station;
            string zipPath = @"D:\dosfiles\SYNOPD\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "_" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "_" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".zip";

            if (File.Exists(zipPath))
            {
                File.Delete(zipPath);
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
                Info += "Вашият архив е създаден в папка D:\\dosfiles\\SYNOPD\\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "_" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".zip" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
                Info += "Вашият архив е създаден в папка D:\\dosfiles\\SYNOPD\\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "_" + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".zip" + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: then debug.. be sure that your directory  holds the value you expect, and work from there

Comment: Can you check the screen show I upload now

Comment: What are the values for `startPath` and `zipPath` when you get this exception?

Comment: the values in startPath is a path to the file.
My file not have any extension and I think startFile is correct ?

for the zipPath - I set where I want to make archive. For example:
D:\dosfiles\SYNOPD\15730_year.month.zip

Comment: If the`zipPath` is ok then `startPath` looks like having problem. Can you share the actual value assigned to it? Also can you check if you can browse to that path via Windows Explorer? You can also check using `File.Exist` to see if the code recognize it as a correct file. You are saying that the `startPath` is a file path but you are using it as Directory in `CreateFromDirectory`. That might be the problem coz the method is expecting a directory path but what you are sending is a file path. You can check by setting `startPath` to some valid directory path just for testing and see if it works.

Comment: startPath and zipPath is look like is ok.. :D

Comment: If it was OK, it wouldn't have thrown exception.